# FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled warning always FALSE

Tags: objective-c, facebook-audience-network

Keep getting WARNING from Facebook Audience Network while doing testing:

*Warning: The value for FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled is currently set to FALSE so you're sending app events without collecting Advertiser ID. This can affect the quality of your advertising and analytics results.*

What I have done:

- App tracking is enable.
- info.plist param is set to TRUE.
  FacebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled
- in Appdelegate.m

> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
>
>     [FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
>     [FBSDKSettings.sharedSettings setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled:YES];
>     FBSDKSettings.sharedSettings.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = YES;
> .. 
> }
> ```

What is going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by moving `Settings.shared.isAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled = true` before `ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)`.